# Are questions about ToCs/EULAs allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions which ask if something is allowed by a game's legalese allowed? For example: "Is it legal to have multiple accounts in the game?"

Comment: If you are looking for actual legal advice, you won't find it on Arqade.

Comment: If its a ToU question which only comes up when you do a certain thing in a game, would the question be acceptable?

Comment: Wouldn't it be wiser to just ask it to the developers/publishers themself? Also: [very much related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161/should-we-avoid-all-legal-questions)

Comment: More often than not this will be in a grey area of our "illegal content" policy. While asking about the ToS would be fine (albeit a bit unreliable, considering you should just ask the people actually making the decision - moderators, game masters, etc.), asking how to circumvent it would not.

Comment: If you're asking whether something is allowed by the ToC, I expect the answer would be along the lines of *Read the ToC*. However if you're asking about the specific implications of a clause in the ToC your answer might be along the lines of 'We are not lawyers.' In both cases they're not really questions that are a good fit for the site.

Comment: The law depends on the country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they could be allowed, but I don't think they should be encouraged. So, I wouldn't vote to close them -- but I would down vote them most of the time.

Such questions will typically show a lack of research effort, and answers will primarily be simply from reading the related documents and quoting portions or pointing the the games web page that answers the question.

At no point is a GM of said game going to defer to our "accepted answer" if it goes against their policy, so it's really not of a lot of use.

[Example question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156916/does-using-bots-in-wow-break-the-tos) -- shows no research effort, answer is a quote of the primary source that's being asked about and is widely available.

Comment: I had a WoW question too, I deleted it because people voted on closing it / downvoted it, there it was a bit more complicated because the solution cannot directly be found in the ToS, and I cant ask a GM because, yeah blizzard GMs...there are rumors that if you ask them a ToS question, the specially keep an eye on you

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Well, if you're asking about something that you know to be questionable, that's probably your answer. If you ask a question, and they say "no, don't do that", then don't do it.

Comment: @RandomDisplayName there are several things about WoW specifically that you can find links for from Blizzard clarifying what is and is not acceptable. In plain English too, not ToS legalese.